# Page Wrap not taking min-height

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```
html ,body {
    height: 100%;
    font-style: Helvetica;
}
.page_background, .page { margin: 0 auto; }
.page_background {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#282828, #888888); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#282828, #888888); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#282828, #888888); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#282828, #888888); /* Standard syntax */
    position: absolute;
    /*height: 100%;*/
}
.page {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 85%;
    min-height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 7.5%;
}

        <div class="page_background">
            <div class="page">
            </div>
        </div>
```

That if the page goes past the full height of the screen (you have to scroll) the background color does not apply. I have `min-height: 100%;` set and tried `height: 100%;`. Neither one seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using the `bottom: 0;` and `position: absolute;` means that the end of the div will be at the bottom of the window.  practically setting that to the `.page` div makes if to have its height equal to the window height, regardless of its content. I am not sure that you can get a CSS only solution, you will need some JavaScript to apply different classes depending on the div's contents

Comment: @Ralph hey please provide us html code or make jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b0txv2m2/4/

Comment: @TasosK. When I take out the `bottom: 0;` and `position: absolute;`, it finally goes the entire height of the page, but the outer div also goes vertically above my inner div.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reset default browser styles - margins, like this

```
html ,body {
  height: 100%;
  font-style: Helvetica;
  margin :0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b0txv2m2/5/

Comment: Have you tried adding some content to try it out? https://jsfiddle.net/b0txv2m2/6/

Comment: Didn't work for me. I already have a reset in place, but I tried what you did and nothing.

Comment: Sorry, haven't noticed worng style there, please take a look https://jsfiddle.net/b0txv2m2/8/

Answer (score 0):

*Prev Ans that was already tried*
Try setting the html and body height like this

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

It should help keeping all contents of the page the full height of the window.

*New Ans* I commented out the position absolute and got this https://jsfiddle.net/dt6p94p9/
Let me know if its what your looking for

```
html ,body {
    height: 100%;
    font-style: Helvetica;
}
.page_background, .page { margin: 0 auto; }
.page_background {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#282828, #888888); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#282828, #888888); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#282828, #888888); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#282828, #888888); /* Standard syntax */
    /* position: absolute; */
    height: 100%;
}
.page {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 85%;
    min-height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 7.5%;
}
```

Comment: @Ralph could you edit the post then, to make sure it's included :)

Comment: Doesn't work. That adds the background color horizontally into the inner div at the end of the page on the bottom , before scrolling.

Comment: Do you only want the black bars on the side? What exactly are you looking to display?

Comment: Yes, like this.. https://jsfiddle.net/b0txv2m2/4/ .. You can even see in this when you scroll the outer div does not maintain it's height.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `position:fixed` its should be work and remove the margin via `margin:0`

Comment: No its fixed. Tell me ? Don't you want scroll bar am i right

Comment: ? I'm telling you it didn't work. I tried what you recommended and it didn't resolve the issue. I tried that previously as well,

Comment: Hey now its 100% okay check this updated link and tell me! I did or not https://jsfiddle.net/80h6mctv/2/