# Outter page wrap doesn't set for the height of the whole page

Tags: html, css

I have the following code that does not cover the full page height if a page has content beyond the normal view port (not having to scroll). If I scroll down the outer div displays for just a small bit and that goes back to white.

Why is the outer div not taking the full height of the page even if it requires scrolling?

```
  html ,body {
    height: 100%;
    font-style: Helvetica;
}
.page_background, .page { margin: 0 auto; }
.page_background {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#282828, #888888); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#282828, #888888); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#282828, #888888); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#282828, #888888); /* Standard syntax */
    position: absolute;
    /*height: 100%;*/
}
.page {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 85%;
    min-height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 7.5%;
}

        <div class="page_background">
            <div class="page">
            </div>
        </div>
```

I created a fiddle to demonstrate what I am doing. You can even see if you scroll in the fiddle, it doesn't take the gray border.

https://jsfiddle.net/1qwwtgjp/

Comment: check answer below is it okay

Comment: possible duplicate of [Page Wrap not taking min-height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032523/page-wrap-not-taking-min-height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Your Main Issue is CSS Positioning**

**See here: https://jsfiddle.net/1qwwtgjp/3/**

You have used `position: absolute;` in your styles, but are looking for your content to flow (and your background height with it).  Remove all the `absolute` positioning, including the `left`, `bottom`, etc, and the explicit height on your `.page` element so it can flow to whatever height it truly is.  This will bring the outer wrapper along with it.

So the new styles for your `.page` class should be:

```
.page {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 85%;
    min-height: 100%;
    /** REMOVE THESE: **/
    /* left: 7.5%; */
    /* bottom: 0; */
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* height: 100%; */
}
```

---

*Old Answer:*

If I understand your question correctly, you may simply not be aware that browsers tend to have default margins on the `<body>` tag.

Simply add a style to remove it:

```
html, body { margin:0; }
```

and see if that solves your issue.

---

Comment: See my edit and give that a try.  Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1qwwtgjp/1/

Comment: When I did that, it basically made the outer div cover the entire page, not just on the left and right bar as I have it set, but when I do this...`.page {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 85%;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 7.5%;
 /*min-height: 100%;*/
 position: absolute;
 /*height: 100%;*/
}` The outer div is positioned right and I can scroll. However, this makes the `.page` inner div, cover my navbar/header.

Comment: "Cover the entire page" -- this is probably because your `.page` div didn't have any content, so it didn't have any height (ie, 0px). This made your background show up.  You have two options - put content in it, or give it a min-height. http://jsfiddle.net/1qwwtgjp/1/

Comment: As an aside, `absolute` positioning is the wrong approach here.  You want your `.page` div to flow, but positioning it absolutely 'pops' it out of the flow of the page.  It will cause all sorts of problems for you.  I'd suggest you read up on CSS positioning to understand better why that choice is usually the wrong one in cases like these.

Comment: If I don't have `position: absolute;` In the `.page` div, the page div goes maybe 1/3 way down the screen. I understand what absolute does. I also have a lot of content on this page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87124/discussion-between-jeremy-penrod-and-becky).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by assigning `overflow` property to `hidden` for the outermost wrapper div.

```
.outerpagewrapperdiv{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This isn't what I am wanting. I want to still be able to scroll. I have a lot of content after the scroll point. I just want the outer most div to to appear after the scroll point

Comment: @Becky , then that is because of the default margin and padding of the body element. You can do this by `body{margin:0;padding:0}`

Comment: I added that and I have the same result. I have a page reset in place, would that mess this up at all?

Comment: @Becky , looks like a browser specific issue, would you tell me which browser you are into and have you checked your issue on other browser ?

Comment: The issue is the same with Chrome and IE. I also get the same results on both with your answer.

Comment: Ok, `. If I scroll down the outer div displays for just a small bit and that goes back to white.` i couldn't see this issue at all on either chrome or on mozilla. Maybe browser not supporting the gradient background and turning into white in your case. what about you give a try with some fixed background color like `background:red` and scroll to make sure it's not because of `gradient`

Comment: Nope, same affect. When I do this with the `.page` inner div. `.page {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 85%;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 7.5%;
 min-height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 /*height: 100%;*/
}` It allows the outer div to go the entire height of the page, but then my `.page` inner div covers everything above it like my header/nav as white.

Comment: @Becky, that is because of the absolute positioning of the div. Assign `position:relative` to any of the parent div of `.page`

Comment: I added relative to .page_background and it didn't help.

Comment: If I take `position: absolute;` off of `.page` it completely kills the `.page` div...or if I make `.page` `relative`